# How to vertically align text when container is smaller than the line height?

Tags: css

I have a small div (26 x 26px), and want to add a single character with font-size: 30px. I would like the vertically-align this text in the box. However, even after setting the `line-height` and `vertical-align` properties, I am unable to raise the text to the center of the container.

Is there a simple way to do this, or do I need to resort to nested divs and transforms?

```css
.zoom button {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    /** these don't see to help **/
    line-height: 26px;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

```html
<div class="zoom">
  <button>-</button>
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you set the line-height to 30px - same the font-size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the minus sign. You can fix it considering a pseudo element where you will apply the `vertical-align` and you adjust its `line-height`.

Note that `line-height:0` will do the job for button element as the content is by default aligned in the center. I also added `vertical-align: top` to avoid a misalignment between the buttons

```css
.zoom button {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.zoom button:first-child::before {
  content: "";
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 20px; /*any value between 17px and 24px will do the job (don't ask me why ...)*/
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom">
  <button>-</button>
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it surprises me that you think the plus sign is aligned. On my machine (OS X 10.13, Chrome 76.0) the plus looks like this in your solution: https://imgur.com/yqFGj4V. Switching your `::before` class to work on both fixes it, but makes me worry about how much browser variability is a factor.

Comment: @SamFen it's related to font-family that's why we don't see the exact same result as we don't have the same default font which related to broswer and OS ... You can consider a specific font-family to avoid falling into the default one

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way seems to me to wrap the text inside an `inline-block` box, from which you set the `font-size` and a `line-height` around 2 third of the font size (for these characters ) , the button will do the centering itself.

pseudo option works too. look @Temani Afif answer

```css
.zoom button {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  padding: 0;
}

.zoom.bis button {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  /* just for info */
}

.zoom.ter button span {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.zoom button span {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 0.66em;/* or 20px .. a third */
}

.zoom {
  margin: 1em;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom">
  <button><span>-</span></button>
  <button><span>+</span></button>
</div>
<div class="zoom bis">
  <button><span>-</span></button>
  <button><span>+</span></button>
</div>
<div class="zoom bis ter">
  <button><span>-</span></button>
  <button><span>+</span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

It has to do something with the '+' character, all other characters are displayed correctly. Try:

```css
.zoom button {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
 }
    
 .plus, .minus {
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="zoom">
    <button><span class="minus">-</span></button>
    <button><span class="plus">+</span></button>
</div>
```